# Arraylist iterator: concurrentmodification

Tags: java, android, iterator, libgdx

occupants is an java.util.ArrayList.

I am iterating through it like so

```
public void hitOccupants(SnakeController snakeController){

    ListIterator<Hitable> i = occupants.listIterator();
    while( i.hasNext()){
        Hitable hitable = i.next();
        if(hitable.hit(snakeController)){//returns true if it should be deleted
            i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

I can figure out why this would give a ConcurrenModificationException...
I am using libgdx, so there could be a threading issue. This is my first libgdx project though, so I am not sure. Running the code on android. Stacktrace:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:71)
        at com.ninovanhooff.snake.model.BoardSpace.hitOccupants(BoardSpace.java:65)
        at com.ninovanhooff.snake.controller.SnakeController.act(SnakeController.java:77)
        at com.ninovanhooff.snake.controller.BoardController.act(BoardController.java:72)
        at com.ninovanhooff.snake.GameActor$2.act(GameActor.java:77)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.act(Actor.java:86)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.act(Group.java:48)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.act(Group.java:48)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:225)
        at com.ninovanhooff.snake.SnakeGame.render(SnakeGame.java:66)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:510)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Comment: Does Hitable.hit modify the list?

Comment: Yes, something else is modifying the list while you're iterating through it. You're correctly using the iterator's `remove()` method in your own iteration, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Yes, what does the `hit` method do?  Paste the code.

Comment: Does this exception happen every time this code runs?  Or only occasionally?  Is there anything special about the list when this happens (single-element list, etc)?

Comment: Voting to close for "Not enough information". The code posted is fine re: using `i.remove()` to modify the list while iterating through it. @Nino: If you can post more information about what `occupants` is and where it's defined, and how the program works, we may be able to help. It may be something as simple as declaring this method `synchronized` if multiple threads are calling it.

Comment: Exception happens every time. My Repo is open, but not committed yet because of these errors. Will commit and post the link to full source here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitable.hit() adds an element to the array, thus causing concurrent modification.

To place this into context:

I am making the classic snake game. When the snake hits the Hitable apple:
1) The apple has to be removed from the BoardSpace's occupants //BoardSpace == tile
 this is done in the code discussed here
2) The snakeś body is elongated into the BoardSpace where the apple was. The snake is now an occupant of the BoardSpace, thus the snake is added to occupants.

Both these are done inside Apple.hit(), ergo: concurrent modification.

Solution: I used a CopyOnWriteArrayList to trave occupants in the original order and contents, and added the elements to be removed for later removal.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Hitable> occupantsSnapshot = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Hitable>(occupants);
    ArrayList<Hitable> removals = new ArrayList<Hitable>();
    Iterator<Hitable> i = occupantsSnapshot.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Hitable hitable = i.next();
        boolean remove = hitable.hit(snakeController);
        if (remove) {//returns true if it should be deleted
            removals.add(hitable);
        }
    }

    for(Hitable hitable: removals){
        occupants.remove(hitable);
        boardController.removeHitable(hitable);
    }
```

For educational purposes: [Bitbucket snapshot](https://bitbucket.org/ninovanhooff/xtreme-snake/commits/33ad8f7fae3f1814fc4cb7dd21bb23d950a660a7)

See AppleController and SnakeBodyParts.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationException as per java docs

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent
>   modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>
> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify
>   a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general,
>   the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances.
>   Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general
>   purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to
>   throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do
>   this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and
>   cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at
>   an undetermined time in the future.

In short one cannot modify list while iterating through it .

There are multiple ways :

1) Create a new list

2) Use of different collections such as Map or Set.

3) Change some state in hitable object

Comment: You can happily modify the list while iterating through it as long as you're using the iterator's remove() method which the OP is; that's what it's for. His issue is actually *something else* modifying the list at the same time.

Comment: @BrianRoach so i miss understood the other answers or are they all incorrect? I don't use ArrayList verry often (actually i am playing with libgdx so i use their Array)

Comment: @BrianRoach ah okay now i understand :P If you use the iterators remove() it is okay, as it was made for this. I need to think about it before posting... I removed my misleading comment

Comment: Every answer that says there is a problem with using the Iterator's `remove()` method is ignorantly incorrect, yes. The OP's issue is that something else, either in the thing he's calling inside the loop or in another thread is *also* modifying the list.

Comment: @BrianRoach so BennX's answer should be correct, as he is talking about multiple Threads editing the ArrayList? OR is he also wrong? And why?

Comment: @Springrbua Unfortunately not. First issue is his answer picks a random Object (`snakeController`) we know nothing about to synchronize on. Second issue is that unless the other thread (if it's another thread) is *also* made to synchronize on that object before modifying the list ... it makes no difference.

Comment: @BrianRoach The SnakeContrroller comes from the OPs question. But yea we don't know anything about it. The synchronized issue is true, yea. Thanks a lot (:

Comment: @Springrbua It's *possible* that the concurrent modification is occurring by another thread calling this `hitOccupants()` method and that his solution *might* work if the `snakeController` is the same instance ... but that's a lot of ifs and mights :)

Comment: @BrianRoach So the OP should give some more informations, where he is using this ArrayList and how. But the error message seems like to occure in the main game thread (stage.act() is called in the game.render() method of the gameloop, and calls act() for all Actors and in the Actor.act() he calls this hitOccupants() method) but it think more infos are needed...

Comment: @Springrbua agreed; in fact I just posted a comment to that effect on the main Q.

Answer (score -1):

You're not allowed to remove items from an ArrayList while iterating through it.  This is done for a number of reasons.  Most obviously, an ArrayList is dynamic, so if you remove the object at index 2, the object at index 3 now shifts down to index 2.  This matters because, while iterating, it could easily lead to an out-of-bounds exception if you were to shorten the length of the list without re-adjusting your iterator.

There are a number of ways to get around this, but there's a standing rule:  if you're iterating, you can't remove.  So either think of a way to do it without iterating (a while loop that only increments the index when hitable.hit is false) or store the objects to be removed in a separate list and then remove those items one by one.

Comment: This is utterly and completely incorrect. The OP is using the iterator's `remove()` method. Why do you think `ListIterator` and `Iterator` have `remove()` methods? In fact you *have* to use the iterator's remove() method to remove something from a list while iterating through it so it can deal with the issues you describe.

Comment: You're correct.  I mistakenly read that the original code had a .remove() before issuing it's .next(), which (at least in the past) would cause this error.  But the code is in the correct order.